# Preserving language session ID from one domain to the next

Tags: session, cross-domain

I have two multi-lingual web sites. The main site and the shop site. On the main site detail page there is a "find in store" button. When the button is pressed, no matter what the language was set to on the main page, the shop page will open the product detail page in the default language (expected).

Is there a way to pass the session setting for language when redirecting to the shop site?

```
<?php
if (!session_id()) session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['languageID'])) {
$_SESSION['languageID'] = 1;//default value
}
?>
<?php
if (array_key_exists('german_x', $_POST)) {            
$_SESSION['languageID'] = 1;
} else if (array_key_exists('english_x', $_POST)) {
$_SESSION['languageID'] = 2;
} else if (array_key_exists('french_x', $_POST)) {
$_SESSION['languageID'] = 3;
} else if (array_key_exists('spanish_x', $_POST)) {
$_SESSION['languageID'] = 4;
} 
?>
```

The URL of the find in store button looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.nameofshop.eu/detail.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_rsDetail['product_id']; ?>" target="_new"><input type="submit" name="goToShop" value="Find in store" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get any answers, so I got creative. Maybe not the best or conventional way to go, but here is what I did, maybe it will help someone else:

Some of the language content is done with includes. I created an html page with a link to the detail page, that had the language session set in the desired language. So, while the English session was running, it would call detail_en.php, while Spanish it would call detail_es.php etc.

This is what the link looks like:

```
<a href="<?php include ('includes/'.$folder.'/findinstore.html');?>" target="_new"><input type="submit" name="goToShop" value="<?php echo $row_rscontent13['description15']; ?>" /></a>
```